# Sortable columns Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm developing a MVC component for Joomla! 2.5 and I want to add some sortable columns in my backend. For this goal I've tried to do the next:

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_sortable_columns_to_a_table_in_a_component

And I got an error "View not found [name, type, prefix]". In this case I have looking for a solution and I find the next:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2638695

Following those indications I have removed the "action" of my "form". In this case my column is sortable, but another problem arises. If I remove the "action" of my "form" then "edit buttom" of my toolbar does not work.

I think there must be another solution because I need working "edit buttom" and sortable column also. I've looking for some similar question here and I've applied the following information:

[How to add sortable columns in a Joomla component (table), both ASC and DESC with an arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783791/how-to-add-sortable-columns-in-a-joomla-component-table-both-asc-and-desc-wit)

&

[Joomla 2.5 -Adding sortable columns to a table in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131673/joomla-2-5-adding-sortable-columns-to-a-table-in-a-component)

But my problem persits. What can I do?? Thank you.

MY RELEVANT SOURCE CODE IS THE NEXT:

> com_inscripciones/admin/models/anuals.php

```
<?php

// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
// import the Joomla modellist library
jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');

/**
 *  Inscripciones List Model
 */
class InscripcionesModelAnuals extends JModelList
{

        public function __construct($config = array())
        {   
                if (empty($config['filter_fields'])) {
                        $config['filter_fields'] = array(
                                'nombre', 
                                'fecha_nac', 
                                'reserva'
                        );
                }
                parent::__construct($config);
        }

         protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
        {
                parent::populateState('id', 'asc');
        }

        /**
         * Method to build an SQL query to load the list data.
         *
         * @return      string  An SQL query
         */
        protected function getListQuery()
        {
                // Create a new query object.           
                $db = JFactory::getDBO();
                $query = $db->getQuery(true);
                // Select some fields
                $query->select('id,nombre,apellidos,nif,fecha_nac,reserva,validacion,clave');
                // From the hello table
                $query->from('#__anual');

                // Add the list ordering clause.                    
                $query->order($db->escape($this->getState('list.ordering', 'nombre')).' '.$db->escape($this->getState('list.direction', 'ASC')));

                return $query;
        }
}
?>
```

> com_inscripciones/admin/views/anuals/view.html.php

```
<?php

// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla view library
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

/**
 * Anuals View
 */
class InscripcionesViewAnuals extends JView
{
        /**
         * display method of Inscripciones view
         * @return void
         */
        function display($tpl = null) 
        {
                // Get data from the model
                $items = $this->get('Items');
                $pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
        $state = $this->get('State');

            $this->sortDirection = $state->get('list.direction');
        $this->sortColumn = $state->get('list.ordering');

                // Check for errors.
                if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) 
                {
                        JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
                        return false;
                }

                // Assign data to the view
                $this->items = $items;
                $this->pagination = $pagination;

                // Set the toolbar
                $this->addToolBar();

                // Display the template
                parent::display($tpl);
        }

        /**
         * Setting the toolbar
         */
        protected function addToolBar() 
        {
        JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('Inscripciones Manager: Curso Anual'), 'inscripciones');
        JToolBarHelper::spacer('10');
        JToolBarHelper::divider();
        JToolBarHelper::spacer('10');
        JToolBarHelper::editList('anual.edit');
        JToolBarHelper::spacer('10');
        JToolBarHelper::divider();
        JToolBarHelper::spacer('10');
        JToolBarHelper::deleteList('¿Desea eliminar esta inscripción?', 'anuals.delete');
        JToolBarHelper::spacer('20');
        }
}
?>
```

> com_inscripciones/admin/views/anuals/tmpl/default.php

```
<?php

// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.multiselect');
?>

<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_inscripciones&view=anuals$layout=default'); ?>"method="post" name="adminForm"id="inscripciones-form">
    <table class="adminlist">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5"> 
                            <?php echo JText::_('ID'); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th width="20">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" value="" onclick="checkAll(<?php echo count($this->items); ?>);" />
                    </th>                   
                    <th>
                            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'NOMBRE', 'nombre', $this->sortDirection, $this->sortColumn); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                            <?php echo JText::_('APELLIDOS'); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                            <?php echo JText::_('NIF'); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'FECHA NAC.', 'fecha_nac', $this->sortDirection, $this->sortColumn); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'RESERVA', 'reserva', $this->sortDirection, $this->sortColumn); ?>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item): ?>
            <tr class="row<?php echo $i % 2; ?>">
                        <td>
                        <?php echo $item->id; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.id', $i, $item->id); ?>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                                <?php echo $item->nombre; ?>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                                <?php echo $item->apellidos; ?>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                                <?php echo $item->nif; ?>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                                <?php echo $item->fecha_nac; ?>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                                <?php echo $item->reserva; ?>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value="<?php echo $this->sortColumn; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value="<?php echo $this->sortDirection; ?>" />
            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant source code, if not we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: OKEY. Relevant source code added. Thank you.

Comment: try removing `nombre` and `ASC` in `$query->order($db->escape($this->getState('list.ordering', 'nombre')).' '.$db->escape($this->getState('list.direction', 'ASC')));`

Comment: thanks for the reply but unfortunately my problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

My query line in model looks like

```
$query->order($db1->getEscaped($this->getState('list.ordering', 'ordering')).' '.$db1->getEscaped($this->getState('list.direction', 'ASC')));
```

and populateState contains

```
$orderCol   = JRequest::getCmd('filter_order', 'ordering');
            $this->setState('list.ordering', $orderCol);
```

and the construct on the filter_fields contains

```
$this->_order[] = JRequest::getVar('filter_order', 'fieldName', 'POST', 'cmd');
        $this->_order[] = JRequest::getVar('filter_order_Dir', 'asc', 'POST', 'word');
```

I had some trouble getting these working in some views in a component I made, just a lot of combinations of things that can be wrong, but you'll get there. I used this tutorial
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already found the bug, but for everyone else, based on the provided code:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_inscripciones&view=anuals$layout=default'); ?>" ...>
```

This line is wrong. Your view call is *&view=anuals$layout=default*.

Correct would be *&view=anuals&layout=default*

The only reason why you got that view error.

Please mark my answer as correct if that was you problem back in 2014.